# add dropdown in kendo listview with add new record event and dont show at edit time

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I am new in kendoUI and I'm trying to learn more and more. I am to try kendo List-view, and I want to add New Record with One Drop-down list. When is edit time I dont want to show Drop-down, just show normal label.

Any idea how can I do this?

Please check this link and give best solution.
[This is list view live demo.](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have one template for editing and one for adding :[JSFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/efSLL/3/) , sorry for the css and you need to tweak the flag reset.

```
 edit: function (e) {
        if (isEdit) {
              listView.editTemplate = kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html())
        } else {
               listView.editTemplate = kendo.template($("#addTemplate").html())
        }
    }
```